# Why does mouse cursor disappear randomly over background image and desktop icons and sometimes foreground windows?

Tags: mouse, cursor

Ubuntu 11.10 64bit (upgrade from 11.04 some months ago), System up-to-date.
HP 6715b 4GB Ram

Sometimes hitting [Esc] will fix it on some foreground windows.

It never shows over System Settings, background or desktop icons (which do flash a highlight as it passes over)

Right now, it shows inside this FF window & FF tabs, but not FF top window status line (name & max/min/close icons) unless I left-click, when grab-hand appears. 
It rapidly changes from visible to invisible as it travels along the left & right edges of the FF window(the 'resize' icon flashes visible to invisible and back to visible as it traverses the border, ending up invisible over the desktop.

I've changed the System Settings - Appearance - Theme a few times without fixing it.

Comment: Which desktop do you use? After a metacity --replace - does the problem then still persist (this disables compiz for this one session - after reboot compiz will be enabled again. If it is a compiz related issue, the problem might dissappear then.

Comment: Where is 'desktop' setting? I don't see it under 'Appearance', 'Screen' or 'Displays'. 'Dash home' didn't seem to give any other meaningful options for 'desktop' either.

Answer (score 1):

I am having similiar issues right now. I noticed after I did a ATI update my cursor went and still having graphic hang ups and cursor vanishes and window borders do. I removed the ATI pack and minor things are fixed but no cursor on the desktop on system windows. only in app windows.